# How to retrieve family tree from database an display diagramatically

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

I am trying to make a family tree creating and editing website. It will be similar to that of http://www.familyecho.com/. I currently have a People table within MYSQL which has a person id as a primary key. A relationships table has the comlums "Person1_id,Person2_id and Relationship(either spouse or parent)". I was curious what kind of recursive function could call back the full family tree of a person and how to then display this diagramaticaly as the family echo website does. I am open to using PHP, Html, javascript or CSS to display.

Comment: Can you show us any code you've done so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345909/mysql-recursion)

Comment: I am currently pulling back everyone in a family tree and placing it in an array using this 
"$array = array();
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM relationships, people WHERE treeid 
 IN (SELECT treeId FROM people WHERE '$_SESSION[Tree]') 
 and (people.Person_id=relationships.Persons1_id
 OR people.Person_id=relationships.Persons2_id)");
 while($row = db_fetch_object($sql)) {
 $array[] = $row->data;  // <<<<----- updated array push
}
 return $array;  "
Then I was thinking I could traverse the array using something similar to this "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304670/family-tree-data-structure"

Comment: I only have a basic understanding of PHP and mysql so i am struggling to understand the best way to approach this. Sorry

Comment: Maybe try the code in the answer of the question you linked and see where it gets you?

Comment: I have it partially returning the tree using this code. But depending on the node it will only display one side of the tree. It also only displays in a small increment and was wondering if this could be displayed in a diagram?

Comment: Just an update. I am now using the Mysql recursion that Michael Kunst linked to it is retrieving the data from my new single table structure that the top answer outlines however i am still curious how to display this as family echo has